# What does -ND argument of ssh mean?

Tags: security, networking, ssh

What does the -ND argument of SSH mean? I didn't manage to find it on the internet.

Example:

```
ssh -ND 8157 master
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-N      Do not execute a remote command.  This is useful for just for‐
         warding ports.

-D [bind_address:]port
         Specifies a local “dynamic” application-level port forwarding.
         This works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the local
         side, optionally bound to the specified bind_address.  Whenever a
         connection is made to this port, the connection is forwarded over
         the secure channel, and the application protocol is then used to
         determine where to connect to from the remote machine.  Currently
         the SOCKS4 and SOCKS5 protocols are supported, and ssh will act
         as a SOCKS server.  Only root can forward privileged ports.  Dy‐
         namic port forwardings can also be specified in the configuration
         file.

         IPv6 addresses can be specified by enclosing the address in
         square brackets.  Only the superuser can forward privileged
         ports.  By default, the local port is bound in accordance with
         the GatewayPorts setting.  However, an explicit bind_address may
         be used to bind the connection to a specific address.  The
         bind_address of “localhost” indicates that the listening port be
         bound for local use only, while an empty address or ‘*’ indicates
         that the port should be available from all interfaces.
```